# Problem arises in finding whether a point exists in a function

Tags: functions

This is the function: $y= - \frac{2}{3}x$

My solving:

$y= - \frac{2}{3}x$

$\frac {2}{3}=  -\frac{2}{3}×-\frac{2}{3} $

$\frac {2}{3}= \frac{4}{6}$

$0.6666= 0.4444$

My teacher put a $\frac {4}{9}$ at the right side in the 3rd step.

Why's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solving - which is correct and your teacher is correct.$-\dfrac{2}{3} \times -\dfrac{2}{3} = \dfrac{-2 \times -2}{3 \times 3} = \dfrac{4}{9}$

Comment: One question: Why is my question got downvoted?

Comment: Thanks. It was $3×3$ $(also = 3^2) $ got depicted to my brain as $3×2$.

Comment: This bot thing prevents me from accepting your answer; it says I can in 4 minutes. Edit: now in 1 minute.

Comment: Finally accepted!!!

Comment: @Gomesz785 since you have asked why it is downvoted there is no downvote in your question but if there is the most probable reason would be the level of question. A such small mistake might not be preferred question for some. Another thing is that please don't create so many unnecessary comments as it is not favourable to people here. Also I would suggest you not to focus so much on accepting answer that write in x minutes now I would accept your answer because it might not be favourable to people here. My focus is now not on writing accepted answer but to help others.

Comment: +1 thanks very much.

Comment: "I doubt how you move from $y= - \frac{2}{3}x$ to  $\frac {2}{3}=  -\frac{2}{3}×-\frac{2}{3} $. This step is wrong."                                                                                         explanation: $y= \frac {2}{3}$ and $x= -\frac {2}{3}$ ; so?